# Vertically centring everything in bootstrap navbar-custom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a Bootstrap 3 nav-bar in my wordpress and customizing it ('.navbar-custom')

I have kept the ability to input a logo in the wp-admin, so it can use the 'wordpress customizer'. The logo is in the top-left as is default and under the default class '.navbar-brand'

However, when a larger logo is used, the elements do not center themselves vertically. (as they do in the default 50px height nav-bar).

Is there any way to make sure everything stays inline with each other (vertically) no matter what size the end-user wants to make there logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could post some code or provide a link to your page.  My assumption is that the logo eventually starts pushing things out of the way that are below it?

If that's the case you might look at making the logo not interact with the surrounding items.  You could set the position to absolute (it'll overlap), set a height and width and turn off overflow or a number of other items.

Let us see what you have and maybe I'll try to give you a better answer :)

Comment: use comments to offer suggestions for improvement `#metacomment`.  Answers should be specific (and answer the question)

Comment: Problem is I don't know where all the code that applies is located. I have the default bootstrap navbar, with automatically vertically centres content with padding, etc. The logo can be adjusted in wp to get bigger, when it does, the padding obviously needs to change. I was wondering if there were resources where the nag relied on other means for link positions